# Codeigniter Google Calendar Library?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-calendar-api

I would like to use the google calender in an application of events and appointments, with codeigniter.

I found out this site

[codeigniter google calender library](http://seanmcgary.com/posts/codeigniter-google-calendar-library)

It is quite good but i saw this line

> Then go to the uri_allowed_chars setting and place a question mark after 'a-z'. This allows you to put question marks in the URL.

This may causing security problem right...? So that is there anyone know another library? Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

That statement in itself does not mean it would cause a security problem.  URL's can have question marks ie: http://localhost/test.php?param=3

It would be more likely that the security issue would be with how you process the request.